# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive - Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, passive-event-listeners

I used the following code and started to get the below mention error what is wrong with the code and what is the fix for it.

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 400) {

    jQuery('.headerN').css("width", "100%");
    jQuery('.headerN').slideDown();
  } else {
    jQuery('.headerN').slideUp();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're not preventing the default action though. Not that you could because `scroll` doesn't have one. Must be another function causing it, are you sure Chrome is referencing the one above?

Comment: Yes you are right I was wrong its not this code its just error there.

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery, it's still an open issue: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871

You can do this with vanilla js on an event:

```
el.addEventListener('someEvent', someFn, { passive: false });
```

this is how someone on the github thread mentioned above created a workaround they implemented:

```
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
    setup: function( _, ns, handle ){
        if ( ns.includes("noPreventDefault") ) {
            this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: false });
        } else {
            this.addEventListener("touchstart", handle, { passive: true });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That workaround is flawed though because you'd want to detect the feature before trying to set the `passive` option. It's still quite new and adding it indiscriminately will crash the script on unsupported browsers.

Comment: you can add those checks, this isn't a complete script. It doesn't make the workaround flawed.

Comment: The first suggestion is fine and actually a good solution when feature detecting. The second one (which is the workaround) is flawed because there would be quite a bit more to restructuring the library's source code, the reason why it is only expected to be fixed in 4.0.

Comment: I'm trusting the [team](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871) to know it's no easy fix. Probably best to stick with vanilla event listeners for now.

Comment: I agree with sticking with vanilla js as that's my preferred approach, I just thought it was relevant to bring up an answer which was accepted by multiple people in that thread as a workaround while also acknowledging (which I did) that the team still has it as an open issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not answering the original question but I am adding the solution which I used and fixed this issue "unable to preventdefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive".

**Why this occurs in jquery?**

```
(S.Event.prototype = {
        constructor: S.Event,
        isDefaultPrevented: Ee,
        isPropagationStopped: Ee,
        isImmediatePropagationStopped: Ee,
        isSimulated: !1,
        preventDefault: function () {
            var e = this.originalEvent;
            (this.isDefaultPrevented = Ce), e && !this.isSimulated && **e.preventDefault();**
        },
        stopPropagation: function () {
            var e = this.originalEvent;
            (this.isPropagationStopped = Ce), e && !this.isSimulated && e.stopPropagation();
        },
        stopImmediatePropagation: function () {
            var e = this.originalEvent;
            (this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = Ce), e && !this.isSimulated && e.stopImmediatePropagation(), this.stopPropagation();
        },
    }),
```

I have taken the code snippet from jquery-3.5.js lib. The snippet in bold causes this issues since the said event(event for which you are getting the issue) is passive, so jquery is not able to preventDefault.

In my case, when i was trying to scroll the dropdown in ipad 11> and selecting any value from dropdown (jquery autocomplete), it was not allowing me to do so.

**Solution**

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
jQuery('#'+event.target.id).trigger('click');
}, {passive: false}
```

This is just a workaround. So, basically, you have to trigger the event manually since the default behaviour is prevented by jquery lib.And the most important part is to mark that event as {passive: false}